# SQL Server rewrite query without using %

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I switched to using prepared statements in my code and I got everything else working, but I'm still stumped by this one. How can I re-write the query without using `%`?

Error (in C# when using prepared statements):

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '@co'.
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.'

My original (working) query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [shortName] 
FROM [xx].[dbo].[yy] 
WHERE [AWScompanyList] LIKE '%1040%'
```

My attempted re-write after switching to prepared statements

```
--Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'xx.dbo.yy' because it is not full-text indexed.
SELECT TOP(1) [shortName] 
FROM [xx].[dbo].[yy] 
WHERE CONTAINS([AWScompanyList], '1040')
```

Comment: Well...the error message is pretty clear. But what isn't clear is why you think you can't have wildcards when using a parameter.

Comment: Where's `'@co'` in the query that failed to parse?

Comment: Your original query does not have @co anywhere in it so im confused

Comment: probably it is wrong query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition could be easily rewritten as

```
SELECT top(1) shortName 
FROM xx.dbo.yy 
where charindex(@co, AWScompanyList) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as this. Assuming you have added a parameter named @co.

```
SELECT top(1) shortName 
FROM xx.dbo.yy 
where AWScompanyList like '%' + @co + '%'
```